# Clean Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning

Currently I have Windows 7 but I want to completly remove Windows 7 and install Ubuntu 13.04.

I have 5 Windows partitions including C: drive. I just want to know whether I will loose all my partitions in Windows. I want to keep the data on those partitions which include my all important data.

Is there a way of doing clean installation of Ubuntu without losing data on Windows partitions?

What happens if I move all my data into one Windows partition (Assume to last Windows partition i.e E:) and then format all other four Windows partitions (Then Ubuntu advance partition menu will identify this total space as a free space) and use advance partition menu to create `/boot`, `/`, `/home` and `swap` area?

Will I be able to extend or merge that Windows E: partition to my Ubuntu home partition after I boot into Ubuntu?

What other types of partitions that we can have in Ubuntu if we want to keep our Movies, Personnel Documents and Study materials in each separate partitions? (Like i did in Windows)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5 partitions with Windows is the extra partition a logical partition in an extended partition, or did you have Windows convert to dynamic partitions. Dynamic partitions do not work with Linux.

Only if you have Windows should you keep a NTFS partition as a data partition. It will need chkdsk on occassion and Linux cannot run that. Linux normally runs fsck on Linux partitions every 40 to 60 reboots automatically.

You can create Linux formatted (ext4 typically) partitions for data if you desire. While you can manually mount with Nautilus each time you reboot, it usually is better to add permanent settings to fstab. You then have to create your own mount points but you can give names that make sense like data, Movies, Music instead of E: or F:. You also have to set ownership & permissions.

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountlinux

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 0):

This question passes by every so often. Just google this site and you will find plenty of answers. In short:

- If you do not know what you are doing, keep at least two backups of your personal data (your other partitions).
- If you want a custom install of ubuntu, do not choose the option to replace windows with Ubuntu, but choose a manual partition table (again, don't do this if you do not know what you are doing).
- The place of your boot system on your hard drive is important (if it is in the beginning your drive will perform better). I would keep two backups of my data (windows partition included) and then do a typical ubuntu install which removes everything. Then you make a new home partition and use something else that ntfs for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved all your data to partition "E", you can format the partitions, but let the "E" remain the same in NTFS when you install the Ubuntu. 
Your data will remain in partition "E" after installing Ubuntu. 
I'm not sure if you will need to automount that partition, but in that case open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config  
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

Maybe you can check a "To do list after installing Ubuntu" for additional configurations.

Comment: why `sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy`?